# Angular 4 - Subscribe gets called mutiple times inside for/switch loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of strings that looks something like this (its random every time)

`["consumables", "spells", "spells", "consumables", "spells", "consumables", "spells", "characters", "characters", "consumables"]`

and then I loop trough this array, and depending on the index i call different `.subscribe` and push some data to new array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++) {  
    switch (arrayOfItems[i]) {
        case 'spells':
            this.spellsSubscribeSet = true;
            this.spellsSubscribe = this.spells.subscribe(data => {
                const itemId = this.getRandom(data.length - 1);
                this.rewardPack.push(data[itemId]);
            });
            break;
        case 'characters':
            this.charactersSubscribeSet = true;
            this.charactersSubscribe = this.characters.subscribe(data => {
                const itemId = this.getRandom(data.length - 1);
                this.rewardPack.push(data[itemId]);
            });
            break;
        case 'consumables':
            this.consumablesSubscribeSet = true;
            this.consumablesSubscribe = this.consumables.subscribe(data => {
                const itemId = this.getRandom(data.length - 1);
                this.rewardPack.push(data[itemId]);
            });
            break;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

.getRandom is a normal function that returns random number.

```
getRandom(x) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
}
```

Strange thing that only 'spells' get called multiple times.

I read something about .flatMap but I don't think that can help me since im looping a normal array.

I'm using firestore database

Comment: Why are you subscribing multiple times? Isn't the point of a subscription to be notified whenever something happens? Therefore you should simply subscribe once to each event, job done. Forget about `switch` inside `for`.

Comment: Or at the very least, don't repeat yourself. `this[arrayOfItems[i]].subscribe` will cover all of your cases, instead of repeating your code 50 times if you have 50 different items.

Comment: @JeremyThille Your comments made me think about other ways I could implement this. So now I'm saving those 3 collections i need in variable on constructor load. And then when I call it later in the code, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I saved all the data I need on constructor load and then used it later in the code, where I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You're loop probably hitting the 'spells' case multiple times which subscribes multiple times to the spells events and therefor the code inside the subscription called multiple times.

In each case you should check if you already subscribed to that event. Something like this:

```
     if (!this.consumablesSubscribeSet){
        this.consumablesSubscribeSet = true;
        this.consumablesSubscribe = this.consumables.subscribe(data => {
        const itemId = this.getRandom(data.length - 1);
        this.rewardPack.push(data[itemId]);
        });
     }
     break;
```